# Select a string in a list of strings linq

Tags: c#, linq

Here I have a list of string in sites1. I need to check the common items between sites1 and items1 and select the matching items from items1. Here is my code

```
 string query = "/sitecore/content/*";
 List<string> sites1 = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.Sites.Select(x => x.StartItem.TrimStart('/')).ToList();
 List<Item> items1 = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems(query).Where(x => x.DisplayName.Contains(sites1)).ToList();
```

Any suggestion?

Edit:
Here i am getting the error while selecting two items

```
 var sites = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.Sites.Select(f => new List<string>() { f.StartItem.TrimStart('/'), f.Language }).ToList();
 List<Item> items = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems(query).Where(x => sites.Contains(x.DisplayName.ToLower())).ToList();
```

Comment: Tried it and getting the following error 'Sitecore.Data.Items.Item' does not contain a definition for 'sites1' and no extension method 'sites1' accepting a first argument of type 'Sitecore.Data.Items.Item' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry mad bad! `sites1.Contains(x.DisplayName)` remove `x.`

Comment: @Rooney: Where do you use "Language" field ?

Comment: @alexm: I need it for later usage

Comment: @Rooney: Do you use "Language" in the second query SelectItems().Where(...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the other way around: `site1.Contains(x.DisplayName)`.
Also, compared to a list `HashSet<string>` is more efficient for multiple look-ups, which becomes noticable as the number of items increases.

```
var sites1 = new HashSet<string>(Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.Sites
        .Select(x => x.StartItem.TrimStart('/')));

var items1 = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems(query)
        .Where(x => site1.Contains(x.DisplayName))
        .ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

I did not notice that SelectItems() returns `IQueriable`. In that case I would re-write the second statement using  `IEnamerable.Any<>` extention method, which can be projected into server SQL query.

```
var items1 = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems(query)
        .Where(x=>sites1.Any(it=>it == x.DisplayName))
        .ToList();
```

**EDIT 2:**
 Correcting the query from the edited question:

```
var sites1 = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.Sites
        .Select(x => new {DisplayName = x.StartItem.TrimStart('/'), Language = x.Language});

var siteNames = new HashSet<string>(sites1.Select(x=> x.DisplayName.ToLower());

var items1 = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems(query)
        .Where(x=>siteNames.Any(it=>it == x.DisplayName.ToLower()))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: DisplayName doesnot exist

Comment: Working fine now..Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Item> items1 = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems(query).Where(x => sites1.Contains(x.DisplayName)).ToList();
```